# Creating a schedule in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, job-scheduling

I am trying to create a schedule which executes on 10th day of month, every month

```
BEGIN
sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
    repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=10',     
    start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP('10-SEP-14 01.46.50.332000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
    comments => 'Schedule run on 10th day of every month',
    schedule_name  => '"STAR1"."SCH_MTHLY_10THDAY"');  
END;
```

But I am getting some errors while doing it
ORA-27486-insufficient privileges (the user itself  is owner of db, dont know why am I still getting thid)

```
ORA-06512- At "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED",line 679
ORA-06512- At "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULAR",line 1130
ORA-06512- At line 1
```

I am doing it first time , I dont know whats going wrong here. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the user is owner of db there is no appropriate privilege as message says.
You had to run:

```
GRANT CREATE JOB TO YOUR_USER;
```

to get more info you can go to: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12384

Comment: This doesn't help. I can't give privileges to myself.

Comment: You should add it from SYS account or other user with SYSDBA privilege.

Comment: Done . Added Using SYS account.